# Postgres aggregator to find common value or null

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view, aggregate-functions

I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE product_variations (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id UUID REFERENCES products,
  attribute1 TEXT,
  attribute2 TEXT,
  attribute3 TEXT
);
```

I'd like to create a view which finds all the attributes that are the same for all variations of a product.  I'm guessing it would look something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW product_shared_attributes AS
  SELECT "product_id", some_aggregator("attribute1"), some_aggregator("attribute_2") 
  FROM product_variations
  GROUP BY "product_id";
```

What kind of aggregator could I use for this?  I would expect it to return the value if all values are the same, and NULL otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of distinct values:

```
CREATE VIEW product_shared_attributes AS
  SELECT product_id,
         CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT attribute1) = 1
              THEN min(attribute1)
         END AS attribute1,
         CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT attribute_2) = 1
              THEN min(attribute_2)
         END AS attribute_2,
  FROM product_variations
  GROUP BY product_id;
```

You could use `max` instead of `min`, but you need an aggregate function. The `CASE` expression results in NULL if none of the conditions apply and there is no `ELSE` branch.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `STING_AGG`

```
CREATE VIEW product_shared_attributes AS
  SELECT "product_id", STRING_AGG ("attribute1"), ',') , STRING_AGG ("attribute21"), ',')
      ,STRING_AGG ("attribute3"), ',')
  FROM product_variations
  GROUP BY "product_id";
```